# block UI when postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

how to block UI when postback from buttons in form or in updatepanel and show "processing...". after return postback unblock UI.

may be jquery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a jQuery plugin called just like that: blockUI

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blockUI